# php scripts get 'exec format error' or 'permission error'

Tags: php, linux, apache, suse

I am getting either an 'exec format error' or a permission error when trying to execute any script on a fresh suse enterprise linux 12 install. It worked on sles 11, but now, even phpinfo doesn't work.

So for testing, I use this simple line

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

which on the command line as through `php -f test.php` works fine. When calling it from a browser using an url in the cgi directory, it leads to an error 500.

The apache error log shows 'exec format error' and 'end of script before output headers' when running it with owner root:root without shebangand line.

When I add an explicit header and a shebang line so that the script looks like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
phpinfo();
?>
```

the result is a 'malformed header' error in apache's log file.

The file's permissions are set to `-rw-r--r--` all the time. When changing ownership from root:root to wwwrun:www, nothing changes. From normal htdocs directory, the browser prompts to download the file.

I have made sure that bot php5 and apache2-mod_php5 packages are installed.

I'd be happy if anyone could give a hint on how to get php scripts running on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out myself:

The mod_php5 package was installed, but that didn't automatically activate it. Do:

```
a2enmod mod_php5
rcapache2 restart
```

The file needs to be configured as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wwwrun www  54 Feb 13 13:43 test.php
```